# How to Make A Two Column Table with long aligned numbers in each row

Tags: tables

I've searched every page under the "Latex tables" google search, along with several other searches, and I can not find a table that looks like this one. Can someone please tell me how to make this:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a fairly straightforward array…

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\setlength{\arraycolsep}{0.4em}% space between columns
\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{0.7pt}% width of lines
\[\begin{array}{c|ccccccccccccc}
n & \multicolumn{13}{c}{f(n)} \\ \hline
1 & 0 & . & 3 & 1 & 4 & 1 & 5 & 9 & 2 & 6 & 5 & 3 & \ldots\\
2 & 0 & . & 3 & 7 & 3 & 7 & 3 & 7 & 3 & 7 & 3 & 7 & \ldots\\
3 & 0 & . & 1 & 4 & 2 & 8 & 5 & 7 & 1 & 4 & 2 & 8 & \ldots\\
4 & 0 & . & 7 & 0 & 7 & 1 & 0 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 1 & 1 & \ldots\\
5 & 0 & . & 3 & 7 & 5 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots\\
\vdots & \vdots & & & & & & & & & & & &
\end{array}\]
\end{document}
```

[image: array]

Comment: Thank you. I'm new to Latex so wasn't sure what else to try besides "table".

Comment: And table is a float, not a tabular or array.